# How to change system navigation programatically?

Tags: android

Is it possible to change system navigation to gesture or 3-button navigation programmatically?

Comment: I know hiding gesturebar systemwide is possible within the phone. I know changing systemwide navigation programatically is possible using ADB. But I've never heard of a method of doing it within the phone like hiding gesturebar. Even if you find a way to do it, you shouldn't use it if you're going to release your app publicly.

Comment: @Shazniq Adb could also help me actually. Do you know the commands?

Comment: @tomas I've updated my answer with the adb commands

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not supported currently.

You can't change navigation in behalf of user. This is an important user preference and enabling apps to change the system navigation type would create confusion only. I don't think it will ever be supported.

Moreover there is no action [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common#Settings) to even "guide" the user to the specific settings screen

On some devices this can be changed with adb commands (but there is no warranty those commands will work in future)

```sh
//Enable gesture navigation
adb shell cmd overlay enable com.android.internal.systemui.navbar.gestural

//Enable 2-button navigation
adb shell cmd overlay enable com.android.internal.systemui.navbar.twobutton

//Enable 3-button navigation
adb shell cmd overlay enable com.android.internal.systemui.navbar.threebutton
```